Comparison of string parameters always return false in Azure DevOps 2022
I have a pipeline script like this:
variables:
- name: chartType
  value: Name
- name: chartPath
  value: 'test'
- name: releaseName
  value: redis-release
- name: chartVersion
  value: latest
- name: valueFile
  value: 'test'

jobs:
- deployment: DeployToEnv
  displayName: Deploy Redis
  environment: ${{parameters.env}}
  strategy:
    runOnce:
      deploy:
        steps:
        - checkout: self
        - script: |
            echo '${{variables.chartType}}'
            echo '${{variables.chartVersion}}'
            echo '${{variables.releaseName}}'
            echo '${{variables['chartType']}}'
            echo '${{variables['releaseName']}}'
            echo '${{eq('Name', 'Name')}}'
            echo '${{eq('latest', 'latest')}}'
            echo '${{eq(variables.chartType, 'Name')}}'
            echo '${{eq('variables.chartType', 'Name')}}'
            echo '${{eq(lower(variables.chartType), lower('naMe'))}}'
            echo '${{ne(variables['chartType'], 'Name')}}'
            echo '${{eq(variables['chartType'], 'Name')}}'
            echo '${{eq(variables.chartType, 'name')}}'
            echo '${{eq(variables.chartVersion, 'latest')}}'
            echo '${{eq(variables['chartVersion'], 'latest')}}'
            echo '${{eq(variables['releaseName'], 'redis-release')}}'
            echo '${{eq(variables.releaseName, 'redis-release')}}'
        - template: '../../Shared/deploy-helm.yaml'
          parameters:
            k8sConnection: $(k8sConnection)
            k8sNamespace: $(k8sNamespace)
            chartType: $(chartType)
            chartPath: $(chartPath)
            chartVersion: $(chartVersion)
            releaseName: $(releaseName)
            valueFile: $(valueFile)

I reference a template deploy-helm.yaml which looks like this:
parameters:
- name: k8sConnection
  type: string
- name: k8sNamespace
  type: string

# Chart
- name: chartType
  type: string
- name: chartPath
  type: string
- name: chartVersion
  type: string
- name: releaseName
  type: string
- name: valueFile
  type: string

steps:
- script: |
    echo '${{parameters.chartType}}'
    echo '${{parameters.chartVersion}}'
    echo '${{parameters.releaseName}}'
    echo '${{parameters['chartType']}}'
    echo '${{parameters['releaseName']}}'
    echo '${{eq('Name', 'Name')}}'
    echo '${{eq('latest', 'latest')}}'
    echo '${{eq(parameters.chartType, 'Name')}}'
    echo '${{eq('parameters.chartType', 'Name')}}'
    echo '${{eq(lower(parameters.chartType), lower('naMe'))}}'
    echo '${{ne(parameters['chartType'], 'Name')}}'
    echo '${{eq(parameters['chartType'], 'Name')}}'
    echo '${{eq(parameters.chartType, 'name')}}'
    echo '${{eq(parameters.chartVersion, 'latest')}}'
    echo '${{eq(parameters['chartVersion'], 'latest')}}'
    echo '${{eq(parameters['releaseName'], 'redis-release')}}'
    echo '${{eq(parameters.releaseName, 'redis-release')}}'

In the first CmdLine task the output looks like this:

In the second CmdLine task in the template itself looks like this:

Even though I have printed the values, they look the same but the comparison is always False for some reason.
Does anyone have any idea? Is this a bug from Azure DevOps 2022?
Thank you in advance

This is not a bug. You are using the wrong variable syntax when you pass the variables to the template parameters.
First, you can check the Understand variable syntax:

In a pipeline, template expression variables (${{ variables.var }}) get processed at compile time, before runtime starts. Macro syntax variables ($(var)) get processed during runtime before a task runs. Runtime expressions ($[variables.var]) also get processed during runtime but are intended to be used with conditions and expressions.

You should also know that runtime variables, which are set during the pipeline run, are not available during template expansion because this process happens early in the run, before the pipeline starts executing. You can refer Template expression for more details.
In your case, the variables are passed to the template using the $(variableName) syntax, which is used for runtime variables and predefined variables.  For example, the value of ${{parameters.chartType}} will be string $(chartType) as the runtime variables are not accessible.

You can download the log from the pipeline, and it will have an azure-pipelines-expanded.yaml in the log package. In the expanded yaml, you will see the actual yaml file you are running in the pipeline. This can explain why the printed the values look the same, but the comparison is always False.


The system encounters a macro expression $(chartType), it replaces the expression with the correct contents of the variable. But the comparison is done during template expansion, so the comparison result will not change when the pipeline runs.
Solution:
You should use the ${{ variables.variableName }} syntax, which is used for template expressions and is evaluated during the template expansion phase. It happens early in the pipeline run.
The modified YAML:
        - template: './Shared/deploy-helm.yaml'
          parameters:
            chartType: ${{ variables.chartType }}
            chartPath: ${{ variables.chartPath }}
            chartVersion: ${{ variables.chartVersion }}
            releaseName: ${{ variables.releaseName }}
            valueFile: ${{ variables.valueFile }}

Test result is that the two script tasks will out put the same values.


Hi, so is there a way to pass pipeline variables (not in YAML script) or variable groups? Because ${{ variables.myPipelineVariable }} returns an empty string.

Hi @NhanNguyen, you can refer the Context, it mentioned that within a template expression, you have access to the variables context that contains all the variables specified in the YAML file plus many of the predefined variables. So, the variables in the variable group can't be accessed with ${{ variables.myPipelineVariable }}, only the variables specified in the YAML file can be accessed with ${{ variables.myPipelineVariable }}.
